# How to download attached file from https web sites with using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, outlook, office365

I want to integrate my app with Microsoft Office 365 Outlook to be able to manage user's account. The user may access his account and may see email without a problem but when the user wants to download attached files program closes immediately.

I tried almost every suggestion on Stack Overflow which exists in other posts and couldn't manage to find the true solution. I also researched about outlook account management for Android and couldn't find helpful information. So I need some suggestion and solutions to handle this.

```
public class hiddenNetwork extends  Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private WebView mWebview;
    ProgressDialog prDialog;


    public hiddenNetwork() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:{
                    webViewGoBack();
                }break;
            }
        }
    };
    public static hiddenNetwork newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        hiddenNetwork fragment = new hiddenNetwork();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


    }
    int count=0;
    private void webViewGoBack(){
        count++;
        mWebview.goBack();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_announcement, container, false);

        mWebview = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);









        mWebview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
                intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension

            }
        });

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    // if want to download pdf manually create AsyncTask here
                    // and download file
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }






            @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                                  WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            }
        });


        mWebview.loadUrl("https://login.microsoftonline.com");

        return view;
    }







    public void myOnKeyDown(int key_code){
        //do whatever you want here
    }
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```